# SQL Query to return any computer with the 7th character is a D

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's what I have but it's returning computers whose 7th character is not a D

```
select * from vComputer where [OS Name] like '%server%' and left(Name, 7) like '%D%'
```

Here is what it returns...

```
CHBDYTPT2K8V3VM
CHBDYSPRMSAPP01
CHBDYSPPAMAPP05
CHBDYSPLNCWEB02
CHBDYSTMSSWEB02
CHBDYSRQPMDBS01
SDFAX01
OLDCOMSOPPRODDB
CHBDYSPEXTADC99
CHBDYSPVRXMAS01
CAPADBDEV1
CHBDYSTODMAPP98
CHBDYSPMSVWEB04
CHBDYSPPAMWEB01
USSUMSDOBICTX01
USSUMSDVRADBS03
```

Comment: @TabAlleman Of right :).

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing is getting the first 7 characters (`left(Name, 7)`) and checking to see if any of those characters is a "d" (`like '%D%'`).

To check only the 7th character, [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) is a great tool:

```
SUBSTRING([Name],7,1)='D'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select *
from vComputer
where [OS Name] like '%server%' and 
      Name not like '______D%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `LEFT(Name, 7) = 'D'` instead of the `LIKE` Operator?

Comment: Because the first 7 characters will probably never equal "D".

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this by using `CharIndex()`

```
select *  
from vComputer 
where  CHARINDEX('d',[name],7) = 7
```

Comment: Thank you!  This also works, one question.  Why do you have to mention 7 2 times?